# Ошибка округления, или currentTimeMills + nanoTime ошибаются?

Tags: java, время, java-8, timestamp

Есть задача - собирать таймштампы с точностью **хотябы до микросекунд** (беру нано, так как из-коробки можно использовать System.nanoTime()), не потому что важна точность, а потому что важно чёткое понимание последовательности. Почему взято время? Потому что оно в любом случае используется, и настроено на всех машинах, где выполняется этот код, значит от него можно относительно точно отталкиваться без потерь в производительности.

Извлекать время решил таким образом:

```
public static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    timestamp.setNanos((int) (System.nanoTime() % 1000000000));
    return timestamp;
}
```

Почему currentTimeMillis? - Потому что java.sql.Timestamp не построить иначе, только через миллисекунды. А так как нужна хоть какая то точность (мне важно чтобы две операции были последовательны, **не важно, например, если конечное время будет с погрешностью в 1 милисекунду**, важно что если "б" выполнялось после "а", чтобы по времени это чётко было видно), затем добавляю наносекунды.

Далее всё попадает в БД. Где, о чудо, я вижу что единичные операции залогированны в другой последовательности!

Несколько дней ломал голову что происходит, пока не написал юниттест, который всё прояснил, вот пример происходящего:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int COUNT = 10000000;
    List<Timestamp> times = new ArrayList<>(COUNT);
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        times.add(getCurrentTimestamp());
    }
    Timestamp prev = times.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i< COUNT; i++) {
        Timestamp current = times.get(i);
        if(current.before(prev)) {
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + ", curr: " + current.toInstant() + ", prev: " + prev.toInstant());
        }
        prev = current;
    }
}

public static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    timestamp.setNanos((int) (System.nanoTime() % 1000000000));
    return timestamp;
}
```

Кратко - тест показывает что в определённый момент времени, очередное логирование таймштампа, ВНЕЗАПНО, показывает время в прошлом. Вот результат вывода в консоль:

```
iteration 6169721, curr: 2023-07-18T12:28:00.103141700Z, prev: 2023-07-18T12:28:00.997348300Z
```

В идеальном примере - консоль обязана быть чистой. Та же ситуация происходит и в юниттестах, они не проходят на достаточно больших выборках.

Подскажите, как более точно считать время, при этом, не допускать считываний и расчёта времени, после которых очередное извлечение штампа приводят в прошлое?

Comment: Кстати, я вот вижу, что есть некая несогласованность в том как я время извлекаю... Сначала я беру миллисекунды, затем нано, но между ними проходит неизвестно сколько времени, и вполне вероятно, что миллисекунда успевает "пересчёлкнуться". Можно завязаться только на наносекунды (upd.нельзя, потому что нет даты)

public static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(time / 1000000000);
        timestamp.setNanos((int)(time % 1000000000));
        return timestamp;
    }

Но нужно мнение понимающих людей...

Comment: Никто не гарантирует монотонность времени, синхронизация часов по интернету может устраивать скачки времени как в будущее, так и в прошлое

Comment: Методы currentTimeMillis и nanoTime возвращают значения разных часов, их в принципе нельзя смешивать друг с другом

Comment: @andreymal, подскажите, как тогда можно нужную точность получить, не смешивая их, и оставаясь на pure java 8?

Comment: При этом, если я правильно понимаю документацию, для nanoTime гарантируется монотонность времени, а для currentTimeMillis нет. То есть если вы хотите сравнивать очерёдность операций, то вам нужно использовать только nanoTime

Comment: ...хотя записывать значение nanoTime в базу нельзя, потому что, согласно всё той же документации, его можно только сравнивать с другими значениями nanoTime из того же экземпляра Java-машины, то есть уже банальный перезапуск программы может всё испортить. Если вы хотите сохранять очерёдность операций, то, может, лучше завести какой-нибудь банальный счётчик и не трогать время вообще?

Comment: @andreymal, распределённый счётчик есть (и на уровне БД, и на Hazelcast), но это довольно тяжёлая операция. Более того, есть некий "протокол" выполнения операций, и он сортируется по времени в том числе, поэтому сразу и завязывался на время (иначе придётся править сотни запросов в БД, которые бы учитывали и новый параметр очерёдности, в случаях когда время в миллисекундах например совпадает), с условием что "просто буду брать более точное, чтобы наверняка...". А тут такая проблема всплыла, когда столько работ по оптимизации было сделано...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147301/discussion-between-test123-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Время 999 миллисекунд и 999 наносекунд.
`System.currentTimeMillis()` возвращает 999.

Прошла одна наносекунда. Время 1000 миллисекунд и 0 наносекунд.
`System.nanoTime()` возвращает 0.

Комбинируем два отсчёта и получаем 999 миллисекунд и 0 наносекунд. Мы оказались в прошлом примерно на одну миллисекунду.

Ещё одна сложность состоит в том что вот такой код не всегда работает правильно:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(ms);
ts.setNanos((int)ns);
```

Здесь предполагается что время в наносекундах `ns` содержит уточняющую добавку ко времени в `ms`. Это не так, вызов `setNanos` стирает часть `ms` не кратную `1000`. Если в `ms` было значение `999`, а в `ns` - ноль, вы получите ноль на выходе. Вы прыгнули в прошлое. Размер прыжка может достигать одной секунды.

Чтобы прыжка не было, нужно сделать `ms` кратной тысяче. А все излишки переложить в `ns`. Тогда код выше первым вызовом установит целые секунды, а вторым вызовом добавит к ним наносекунды.

Вот рабочий код:

```
private static long baseMs;
private static long baseNs;
static {
    long ns0 = System.nanoTime();
    baseMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ns1 = System.nanoTime();
    baseNs = ns0 + (ns1 - ns0) / 2;
}

private static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
    // текущее время 1000000 * ms + ns
    long ms = baseMs;
    long ns = System.nanoTime() - baseNs;

    // текущее время по прежнему 1000000 * ms + ns
    // но теперь ns не более одной миллисекунды
    ms += ns / 1000000;
    ns %= 1000000;

    // текущее время по прежнему 1000000 * ms + ns
    // но теперь ms содержит целые секунды
    ns += 1000000 * (ms % 1000);
    ms -= ms % 1000;

    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(ms);
    ts.setNanos((int)ns);
    return ts;
}
```

В предыдущем коде есть два деления. Число делений можно уменьшить если базовые времена `baseMs` и `baseNs` установить на границу целой секунды:

```
private static long baseMs;
private static long baseNs;
static {
    long ns0 = System.nanoTime();
    baseMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ns1 = System.nanoTime();
    baseNs = ns0 + (ns1 - ns0) / 2;

    // move baseMs on integer second
    long shiftMs = baseMs % 1000;
    baseMs -= shiftMs;
    baseNs -= 1000000 * shiftMs;
}

private static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
    long ns = System.nanoTime() - baseNs;

    // ms contains integer seconds
    long ms = baseMs + 1000 * (ns / 1000000000);
    ns %= 1000000000;

    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(ms);
    ts.setNanos((int)ns);
    return ts;
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно так и происходит. Вот думаю, как сделать замер один раз, а не два, и сразу точный. Пока вычисляю - проходит время, и результат уже некорректный. Нужен один точный замер, мне это несколько раз подсветили.

Comment: К сожалению, ваш код не работает. Я тоже сначала подумал копать в эту сторону. Но nanotime хранит только милисекунды, остальное время и дату он не хранит, а значит снова проблема смешения двух времён.

Comment: nanoTime хранит время до 292 лет примерно.

Comment: @ Stanislav Volodarskiy, вы точно про java 8 говорите? В моей версии не хранит ничего кроме наносекунд. Вот ваш пример выдаёт такое время: 1988-09-07 20:21:32.4922466

Comment: Как я понимаю он возвращает время от запуска процесса. Чтобы получить календарное время нужно добавить константное смещение к миллисекундам. Смещение вычисляется один раз на старте процесса.

Comment: Чтобы тут не плодить комментарии, сможете в чат присоединиться? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147301/discussion-between-test123-and-andreymal

Answer (score 1):

1. **Нельзя смешивать разные источники получения времени**. Это первая ключевая ошибка, она хорошо описана в комментариях и в одном из ответов.
2. **Использовать System.nanoTime - так же нельзя**, связано это с тем, что рассматривая в рамках одного потока и одного ядра процессора вроде как можно рассчитать смещение даты+времени, и прибавлять его к нанотайму, получая более менее точную дату. Но в случае когда у нас более одного ядра, и более одного потока всё это не работает. Проблема описана здесь: https://dolzhenko.blogspot.com/2012/11/java-nanotime.html?m=1
3. **Адекватных средств замера времени в java 8 с точностью до микросекунд я не смог найти**, если кто знает, буду благодарен. Это значит что моя проблема не может решиться в лоб.
4. Конкретно для моего случая может помочь комбинированный способ, мне нужно использовать время как время, и как некий ИД, соблюдающий порядок, отсюда путь решения очевиден (не сразу дошёл до него), используя максимальную точность расчёта времени в 8 версии java получаем миллисекунды, далее у нас есть теоретически возможные порядка 1000000 операций замера в одну миллисекунду. Давайте сделаем счётчик замеров в данную миллисекунду, синхронизируем его и добавим ко времени. Да, это не будет точным временем, но оно решит все проблемы:

   ```
   private static long prevMills = System.currentTimeMillis();

   private static final AtomicInteger nanosActions = new AtomicInteger(0);

   public static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
       long mills = System.currentTimeMillis();
       if(prevMills != mills) {
           prevMills = mills;
           nanosActions.set(0);
       }

       Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(mills);
       // Это ненастоящие наносекунды, а миллисекунды, к которым подмешан счётчик операций замеров в данную миллисекунду
       // старая версия - int fakeNanos = ((int)(mills % 1000)) * 1000000 + nanosActions.incrementAndGet();
       int fakeNanos = timestamp.getNanos() + nanosActions.incrementAndGet(); // Так быстрее
       timestamp.setNanos(fakeNanos);
       return timestamp;
   }
   ```

Таким образом, мы получаем и время, и счётчик, гарантирующий строгую очерёдность замеров на одной ноде. Как я говорил ранее - междунодовые операции сопоставимы по длительности с миллисекундами, поэтому для моей задачи данной точности хватает.

Многопоточный вариант:

```
    private static final Map<Long, AtomicInteger> nanosMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Long, AtomicLong> prevMillsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    /**
     * Метод-фикция, относящийся больше не ко времени, а к порядку вызовов getCurrentTimestamp
     * В рамках текущего потока, вызовы будут гарантировать строго возрастающую последовательность.
     * @return Время [дата+время+миллисекунды][счётчик]
     */
    public static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
        long mills = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Обеспечиваем атомарность доступа в рамках каждого потока
        long tickId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        AtomicInteger nanosActions = nanosMap.computeIfAbsent(tickId, key -> new AtomicInteger(0));
        AtomicLong prevMills = prevMillsMap.computeIfAbsent(tickId, key -> new AtomicLong(0L));

        if(prevMills.get() != mills) {
            nanosActions.set(0);
        }

        // Так как у нас java 8, в ней нет точного времени, только миллисекунды.
        // Нам важна строгая последовательность замеров, поэтому, используем миллисекунды как опору,
        // если в одну миллисекунду вызывают несколько замеров, просто повышаем счётчик замеров,
        // у нас в распоряжении теоретические 1000000 значения для наносекунд, этого с головой хватит.
        int counter = nanosActions.incrementAndGet();

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(mills);
        // Собираем время [дата+время+миллисекунды][счётчик]
        // старая версия - int fakeNanos = ((int)(mills % 1000)) * 1000000 + counter;
        int fakeNanos = timestamp.getNanos() + counter; // Так быстрее чем в старой версии
        timestamp.setNanos(fakeNanos);

        prevMills.set(mills);

        // Это не точное время, тем не менее, оно удовлетворяет всем необходимым условиям,
        // да и кто проверит точность микросекунд или даже наносекунд??
        return timestamp;
    }
```

Comment: Установка fakeNanos сбрасывает миллисекунды. Во времени которое вы получили, только секунды настоящие. А можно было бы сохранить и миллисекунды.

Comment: Можно так: `ts = new Timestamp(mills); ts.setNanos(ts.getNanos() + добавка);`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, сброса нет. Внимательно посмотрите как фейковые секунды считаются. Извлекаются настоящие миллисекунды и к ним прибавка идёт уже фейковая. А так да, согласен, + быстрее сделать чем остаток от деления искать, это можно оптимизировать

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, у меня во втором примере была опечатка, в коде правильно, а тут неправильно было. Поправил, вернул правильное умножение.